# How to create proxy in java

Tags: java, proxy

How do they create proxy of a `class` in java. Do they create the proxy on as needed basis or they create it and have it around forever.

Comment: yeah, what context are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean the proxy object or the proxy class?

Comment: "They" means people/programmers :D

Comment: "They" => java developers
actually @javaguy want to ask how to  create runtime class in java. For example. Arrays in java also creates class at runtime. That is called proxy class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933993/what-are-dynamic-proxy-classes-and-why-would-i-use-one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create proxies in two basic ways:

- using the JDK mechanism, by interface. Take a look at [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).
- using some byte-code generation/manipulation library, on a concrete class. Take a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) and [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

Apache has a nice utility: [commons-proxy](http://commons.apache.org/proxy/). It wraps many mechanisms and frameworks for creating proxies.

This is all about dynamic proxies - i.e. those created at runtime. For static proxies - see [wikipedia about the proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

Note that you are not making a proxy of a class - you are making a proxy of an object.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments that the question is a little vague. However, I'd suggest you look at some of the mocking frameworks such as easymock and mockito. Their source code is available and their core functionality is creating proxies of class and interfaces. So they are good concrete examples of how to go about creating proxies.