# Why does casting an enum to any interface not cause a compilation error in Java when the enum type contains at least one "extended" enum?

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors, compilation

The following code compiles:

```
    public enum Foo {
        A,
        B{};
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Foo f = Foo.A;
            List s = (List)f;
        }
    }
```

This one doesn't:

```
public enum Foo {
        A,
        B;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Foo f = Foo.A;
            List s = (List)f;
        }
    }
```

I could also replace `Foo.A` with `Foo.B` and get the same result.
What is going on here? How could `Foo.A` ever be a `List` in the first example?

Comment: I guess the compiler reasons that since your enum does have subtypes, that it could have a subtype that implements the interface; even though it actually does not.

Comment: I tried to compile your first example and it doesn't work (made enum non-public and moved `main` to separate public class tho). Edit. it compiles but throws `ClassCastException` during execution.

Comment: @Amongalen yes that's the point. There will always be a `ClassCastException` and I do not understand why the compiler wouldn't know :)

Comment: @khelwood as far as I know `enum` in Java cannot inherit from another type.

Comment: @HansWurst Actually, I think enums can implement interfaces, just not extend classes since they already extend `Enum`

Comment: @user yes you can but `Foo` actually doesn't and Java does not allow "subenums" so there is no type that is a `Foo` and implements `List`

Comment: @HansWurst Yeah, you are right about that. Perhaps all the Java compiler checks is that there are subclasses of `Foo` and doesn't bother checking if any of them actually implement `List`

Answer (score 3):

For this type of casting, the [spec on Narrowing Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) defines the rules. There is no special case for enums, only a distinction between final and non-final classes.

The basic enum falls into the "final class" category, but your extended enum doesn't, as it introduces a subclass via the `{}` syntax.

Of course, even with the extended enum, there's no way that one of your enum constants could ever implement `List`, but the current spec simply doesn't cover that situation.

A future revision of the spec might improve that, and then I'd expect compilers to implement the additional checks. But right now, that degree of compile-time safety isn't available.

Comment: Mhh that is surprising as `javap Foo.class` gives me `public class Foo extends java.lang.Enum<Foo> {
...
}`
for both.

Comment: @HansWurst I guess someone can add an interface to that enum, _at runtime_.

Comment: @HansWurst [there you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32124809/2711488)…

Comment: @Eugene it’s possible (see my previous comment), but I don’t think that the Java language designers considered this possibility when defining the rules. It just has not been considered to add a special rule for `enum` types, so the combination of existing rules leads to the behavior we’re seeing here.